# SerialTimeoutException crashes script

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

This script crashes due to a serial timout exception after an extended period of time. It's been making it to 5000 loops or so before it has the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\3d Exposure\Desktop\venderFix.py", line 69, in <module>
    A.setHigh(12)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\arduino\arduino.py", line 30, in setHigh
    self.__sendData('1')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\arduino\arduino.py", line 58, in __sendData
    self.serial.write(str(serial_data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 270, in write
    raise writeTimeoutError
SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout
```

Why would it time out after working perfectly for so long? How do I stop it doing so?

```
import json
import urllib
from pprint import pprint
import time
from arduino import Arduino

##############################################################
#Change to suit the Mars Bars, currently at 0.2 of a second  #
vendtime = 0.2                                               #
                                                             #
#Delay Time Between each Search (never below 15 seconds)     #
delayTime = 15                                               #
#This is the search term for the URL. (%23 = #)              # 
searchTerm = '%23happy'                                      #
                                                             #
A = Arduino('COM3')                                          #
A.output([13]) #Output on pin 12                             #
##############################################################


#to collect the first tweet without vending
countTweet = 0
#To test Twitter for consistancy 
tweet= 0
noTweet= 0



#the infinate loop
while True:

    #j contains the JSON we load from the URL
    j =json.loads(urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+searchTerm+'&result_type=recent&rpp=1&filter:retweets').read())

    #Debug JSON from twitter (for faults on the Twitter end or possible GET limit id below 15 seconds per request)
    #pprint(j) #needed for debugging only

    #find the text and the tweet id
    if 'results' in j and j['results']:
        text = j['results'][0]['text']
        id = j['results'][0]['id']
        #how many times the Json is complete
        tweet+= 1
    else:
        #How many times the Json is incomplete (sometimes twitter malfunctions. About 0.1 in 100 are broken)
        noTweet += 1

    #print the text and id to the screen
    pprint(text) #needed for debugging only
    pprint(id)   #needed for debugging only

    #to get the existing tweet from before we power on, if the first ID has been stored already (count == 1)
    if countTweet != 0:  #if countTweet is not equal to 0 then it's not the first tweet
        #pprint ("new loop") #needed for debugging only

        #if lastID is not equal to ID
        if lastID != id:
        #Tell Arduino to Vend
            #pin 12 HIGH
            A.setHigh(13)
            #Sleep for the time specified in vendtime
            time.sleep(vendtime)
            #pin 12 LOW
            A.setLow(13)
            #Display the tweet that triggered the vend
            #pprint(text) #needed for debugging only
            #pprint(id)   #needed for debugging only
            #Make lastID equal to ID so that next time we can compare it 
            lastID = id
            #pprint ('lastID updated') #needed for debugging only
        #if no new tweets, print     
        else:  #needed for debugging only
            pprint ('no new tweets') #needed for debugging only
    #If it's the first loop, confirm by printing to the screen
    else:
        pprint("First loop complete")
        pprint(text)
        pprint(id)
        lastID = id
        pprint(lastID)
        countTweet += 1 #Add 1 to countTweet

    pprint ('Number of Tweets')
    pprint (countTweet)
    pprint('Working JSON')
    pprint(tweet)
    pprint('Broken JSON')
    pprint(noTweet)

    pprint('waiting')
    time.sleep(delayTime)
```

For communication with the Arduino I am using the Python Arduino Prototyping API v2. It works well, this is the first and only issue in serial I have had with this script.
I imagine I need to set a timeout myself although I am not 100% sure how to ensure this would not have the same or a similar problem.

Comment: I see no baud rate here, or data rate. But what this would be is that you are filling the serial buffer and then the new writes fail. That or you are trying to write while another write is in progress.

Comment: @Serdalis How would I stop this from happening?

Comment: You don't have enough information in your example for me to say. But usually you need to see if your baud rate can handle the amount of data you are trying to push through. If it can't, you need to wait till the buffer is empty before writing again.

Comment: @Serdalis This is sending a message to send pin13 HIGH probably once every half an hour on the less popular hastag searches that I use. Sometimes It will go 24 hours without use.
Would not sending serial data for hours effect this? 
How can I learn to check the buffer is empty?

Comment: Hmm I misunderstood your example. Buffers won't come into play here. Check to see what the state of the pin is when you call the high / low functions, maybe you're setting it to a value it is already at. Also check the connection, write timeouts also occur when the connection is down (specially after long pauses). You might not be sleeping long enough, set it to 1 and see what happens. Sorry I can't give anything conclusive.

Comment: @Serdalis That's a great help thanks. I'm going to put my money on the connection being down after a long pause. Do you think it would help to switch an unused pin every time it loops? That would reduce the time between serial communication to about 16 seconds.

Comment: 16 second pulses should be good, I don't know how these devices handle keep-alive, usually serial stays alive until killed, and annoyingly beyond... Checking for write failures may be the only way you can see if the connection is down, on a few of my projects it was. Hope this was enough to help.